# How logout from Django AdminLTE iFrame?

Tags: django, adminlte

**AdminLTE**
https://adminlte.io/themes/v3/iframe.html

hi,  I am Django beginner and try AdminLTE templates above to my Django.
In my Django, when click logout link to redirect login page is default action.

In this template,  there is no button/link for logout.
So after add to top-navi a link <a href="/logout/">logout</a> and click it.
Django try to load logout template 'logout.html' to iframe and it was fail.

It looks fail logout.

When reload this page as is, it displayed login page. seems Login sessions is abandoned now.
But without reloading page and click any link, it load template to iframe tab normally and that dead session is reborn.

How can I logout this page?
regards.

Answer (score 0):

solved.

add JavaScript this page,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function logout(){
        location.href='/logout/';
    }
</script>
```

and add onClick event to logout-link

```
<a href="#" onClick="logout()">Logout</a>
```

It can redirect to login page through the logout page. It is default action on my site.